# POST curl to url throws `Top layer JSON is of unexpected type` error

Tags: curl, post, terminal

When I curl the following (url and bearer token obscured):

```
curl -d '{"search":"2b037f6f-2b12-4819-9f21-efca9371351c"}' -X POST "https://demo.platform.com/api/search/v1/branches/main/search?include_aggregations=true&include_summary=true&limit=10" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer {token}"
```

I cannot see what is wrong and why the following error would be thrown:

```
{"code": "JSON_FORMAT_ERROR", "error_id": "01FSM2Z91QT61S77M41831NYED", "request_id": "0bd29f82-8add-43c7-bb5e-e507eac12d3c", "description": "Top layer JSON is of unexpected type", "detail": {"expected_format": "<class 'dict'>", "actual_format": "<class 'NoneType'>"}}%
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It works with the addition of `-H "Content-Type: application/json"`